# How to fix "Invalid rule result: Instance of class Promise." while creating my first application "ng new myfirstApp"

Tags: angular

Creating first Angular Application using "ng new Appname"
I am stuck on 2nd question "Which stylesheet format would you like to use?"

It shows me error message "Invalid rule result: Instance of class Promise."

I tried selecting different options from css preprocessor list

[Invalid rule result: Instance of class Promise. Error message creating Angular first Application on css question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuV5g.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Remove node_modules folder & install @angular-cli again

ref https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11759

Comment: @SteveHawk Can you please accept this as an answer?